# extract and store coordinates in the dataframe using shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I can click and extract the coordinates from the plot. Here is the [link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html). Can someone please tell me how can I extract and store these coordinates in a tibble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked the accepted answer a little bit to **remove the if-else block** as I find it easier to read.

Original code:

```
# Create the table or update the values.
observeEvent(c(input$plot_click$x, input$plot_click$y), {
  if (is.null(df())) {
    df(tibble(x = input$plot_click$x, y = input$plot_click$y))
  } else {
    df(df() %>%
      add_row(x = input$plot_click$x, y = input$plot_click$y))
  }
})
```

Replacement:

```
# Create empty tibble    
df<-reactiveVal(tibble(x=numeric(),y=numeric()))
# Now add new row after each click
observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
  df(df() %>% add_row(x = input$plot_click$x, y = input$plot_click$y))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it could be like this:

1. Create a `reactiveVal` to store the `tibble`.
2. Update the data every time a new point is selected.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click",width = '1000px', height = "1000px"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info"),
  tableOutput("tibbl"),
  actionButton('save_to_global', "Save Table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
  })
  
  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
  })
  
  #create the table or update the values.
  observeEvent(c(input$plot_click$x, input$plot_click$y), {
    if (is.null(df())) {
      df(tibble(x = input$plot_click$x, y = input$plot_click$y))
    } else {
      df(df() %>%
           add_row(x = input$plot_click$x, y = input$plot_click$y))
    }
  })
  
  output$tibbl <- renderTable({
    df()
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$save_to_global, {
    assign('df_coordinates', df(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find the output (tibble) in my environment

Comment: Do you want to save it to the global environment outside the app?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract few coordinates and store in the global environment and do some post processing.

Comment: Also, can you please tell me if there is a way to see the larger plot to b able to click more accurately

Comment: @SiH I added an actionButton that sends the tibble to the global envir.  Since R is busy when running a shiny app the data will be available in the global envir once the app closes. With respect to the size of the plot, you can control that with height and width arguments in `plotOutput` function.